# MySql #1052 how to fix?

Tags: mysql

How to fix this ? (I think its in last JOIN)

```
SELECT id, prumer
FROM 
SELECT id, AVG( s ) prumer
FROM hodnoceni
GROUP BY id
)p
JOIN (
SELECT MIN( prumer ) nejhorsi, MAX( prumer ) nejlepsi
FROM (
SELECT id, AVG( s ) prumer
FROM hodnoceni
GROUP BY id
)p
)q ON p.prumer = q.nejhorsi
OR p.prumer = q.nejlepsi
JOIN op_add r ON p.id = r.id
```

Something in `JOIN op_add r ON p.id = r.id`

Please help me ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not much clear but your query is syntactically wrong. It should be something like

```
SELECT id, prumer
FROM (
SELECT id, AVG(s) as prumer
FROM hodnoceni
GROUP BY id
) p
JOIN (
SELECT MIN( prumer ) nejhorsi, MAX( prumer ) nejlepsi
FROM hodnoceni
GROUP BY id
)q ON p.prumer = q.nejhorsi OR p.prumer = q.nejlepsi
JOIN op_add r ON p.id = r.id;
```

Well, your posted query is total weird and there isn't enough information to say what's that you are looking for and hence suggested solution is only for *syntactical mismatch*. Your query should be like

```
SELECT p.id, p.prumer
FROM (
SELECT id, AVG(s) as prumer
FROM hodnoceni
GROUP BY id
) p
JOIN (
SELECT MIN(prumer) as nejhorsi, MAX(prumer) as nejlepsi
FROM (
SELECT id, AVG(s) as prumer
FROM hodnoceni
GROUP BY id
)pp
)q ON p.prumer = q.nejhorsi OR p.prumer = q.nejlepsi
JOIN op_add r ON p.id = r.id;
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'prumer' in 'field list' :(

Comment: it is a question that finds the best worst average of any rating

Comment: Translate: Hodnocení = Ratings, Prumer = AVG, Nejhorsi = Worst, Nejlepsi = Best   Sorry this scricpt not avaible for english :D

Comment: 1st. "#1054 - Unknown column 'prumer' in 'field list'"

Comment: 2nd " #1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous" :(

Comment: @KubaHon, see edit again and try the edited version of query (below one)

Comment: work! but I need to get data from a table "op_add" FROM "images"

Comment: I'm sorry to trouble is that the more you add?

Comment: @KubaHon, that's a separate question and so post it separately.